# Essere complici

Tags: word-usage

Leggendo di una campagna del comune di Roma contro l'abbadono degli animali ([sito del comune](https://www.comune.roma.it/web/it/notizia/al-via-la-campagna-estiva-contro-labbandono-degli-animali-se-abbandoni-sei-complice.page)) sono rimasto colpito dallo slogan "Se abbandoni, sei complice!".

Nello specifico si spiega che

> “Roma ci dice che non bisogna abbandonare gli animali, perché se abbandoni sei **complice**. Ed è vero. Agli animali si può soltanto voler bene, accarezzarli, coccolarli, salvarli dai canili, portarseli a casa e dargli tutto l’affetto che meritano, perché te ne danno altrettanto. Evviva chi non abbandona i cani e chi si adopera per restituire a questi animali una vita nuova”

Normalmente l'uso di complice presuppone il prendere parte ad un'azione criminosa non essendone il principale (quantomeno non essendone l'unico) artefice (es. [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/complice/)), ma in un contesto simile non è chiaro *di chi* si sarebbe complici.

Esiste un uso alternativo, magari recente, della parola complice in un senso più generico di *cattiva persona (?)*? O si tratta magari di una scelta per attirare l'attenzione con una frase ambigua?

Comment: Secondo me la tua intuizione è corretta (complice usato nel senso di "cattiva persona"), ma non sono sicuro che si tratti di un effetto di ambiguità voluto oppure semplicemente pessima comunicazione.

Comment: Interessante. Forse chi l'ha scritto intendeva qualcosa come “complice [delle varie altre cose brutte che succedono al mondo]”, come a dire “magari non ti sembra grave fare questa cosa, ma in realtà ti pone allo stesso livello di chi uccide, ruba, fa violenze varie”.

Comment: Un'altra parola che viene adoperata piuttosto a sproposito è *delitto* nel senso di *omicidio*: “il delitto di X”, nel senso che X è la vittima. Qui mi pare ci sia un'arbitraria estensione di significato: un complice è sì qualcuno coinvolto in un reato, ma dev'essere specificato quale, direttamente o tramite la persona di cui si è complici.

Comment: Curiosamente, però, la prima accezione che appare nel [Battaglia](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI03/GDLI_03_ocr_421.pdf) è "Chi  partecipa  a  un’azione 
criminosa  (o,  in  genere,  riprovevole)": non menziona che si deva partecipare con altri.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In quanto madrelingua italiano, concordo nel dire che il tuo dubbio è lecito. Se interpretato in un modo molto "elastico", si può dire che "se abbandoni sei complice del sistema di abbandono", che ovviamente è una forzatura. È come dire che "se uccidi sei complice di chi approva l'omicidio": un'inutile ricorsione di termini.

Analizzando il contesto comunicativo italiano in maniera più ampia, posso dirti che si tratta molto probabilmente di una scelta di efficacia comunicativa (che molto spesso trascende la sintassi): una frase molto celebre in Italia è "chi dimentica è complice". Significa - più o meno - che chi dimentica le tragedie della storia, è "complice" nel favorirle nuovamente nella storia attuale.
Questa frase è stata probabilmente "modellata" per renderla simile, e quindi più efficace dal punto di vista propagandistico.